# Execute asynchronous and synchronous code in the same describe in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine, protractor

In protractor, I am trying to execute number of test using "for" loop, the problem is that the loop stop value is depend on asynchronous "it" test case.

```
describe ("[Windows] My Account - History", function(){

//The Page Object I use
var grid    = new Grid();

//Initialize grid object in it test case
it("Initialize the grid object from the DOM",function(){
    grid.init();
});

//create number of test iteration
for(var counter = 0;counter < grid.windowInfo.length; counter++){
    it("Test 1",function() {

    });

    it("Test 2",function() {

    });
}
});
```

Here the `grid.windowInfo.length` in not init with the correct value because the init "`it`" test case is sent to the queue, and executes the `for` loop first.

Comment: Do you see your `Test 1` and `Test 2` `it`'s being executed in console? Using `for` loop outside an `it` doesn't execute it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the way you can test such a feature. Make the `it` first, then the `for` inside, then check that all the results match. So the `it` will succeed only if all the loop executed as expected.

Else, you can do `if("Test " + counter, ...` but it would probably be a bad idea and a poor test because if `windowInfo` is empty, your test will be OK and I don't think it's what you want.